# GetCoverage request - don't load result into memory and directly to hard drive

Tags: r, ogc, wcs, http, getcoverage

I want to make a `GetCoverage`-request against a server and download more or less 24 GB of data.

In R I would do something like this:

```
library(httr)
res = GET("server...REQUEST=GetCoverage...")
```

Can I now download the data directly to my hard drive?

Because this way, I'm assuming the data gets put into memory. At the moment the result is simply `NULL` and I don't know why. A smaller `GetCapabilities` and `DescribeCoverage` result in statuscode 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R `download.file` will take a URL and store the response in a file without ever keeping it in memory.